# How to set the standard folder from which to read the file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to create a small puzzle game. My problem is to set the folder where the app reads pictures. Is possible to create in the drawable folder another folder called "images", and insert in this folder the pictures that the app reads ?

I'm using:

```
((SelectImagePreference) findPreference(IMAGE_SOURCE)).setCustomLocation(data.getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use assets folder http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/06/14/Android-Beginners-Intro-to-Resources-and-Assets.aspx